# Check services running on the server and restart them if they have stopped? (python script)

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, mysql, ssh, mongodb

I am trying to write a python script which shows me the services which are running on my server.

The thing is that mongodb keeps going down on the server and each time it happens I have to manually write the command to start it up.

What I wanted to do was automate this job for some services if they go down.

Currently i have written this https://gist.github.com/prodicus/8993357d3cf49759835e

I know its really basic guys. It has miles to go :)

Now how do I start the services **mongodb** and **apache** through this script ?
Any suggestions would be really helpful guys.

Answer (score 5):

There should be no need to reinvent this wheel, it's been done plenty of times before.

Depending on your OS/Distro then there should be a [process supervisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_supervision) you can leverage already available. Currently systemd and upstart are fairly common.